# Angular 8: How to bind query parameters to input field

Tags: angular

I have a search page with an input field, much the same as the example in the Angular docs (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name). As the user types a search term in the input field an ajax request is sent and the search results are displayed on the screen.

I would like to be able to 2-way bind the search term in the input field to a URL query parameter so that the URL always represents the details of the current search and can then be shared via email, etc.

I can't find any examples of this being done. The ActivateRoute.queryParamMap looks to be read only.

My code so far is pretty much the same as the hero-search component of the  live example from Angular.
https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt6/stackblitz.html

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: @atalantus, added a link to the live example from Angular. The page I'm creating is based on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- When user type in the search box, you need to change the query-string:

  ```
  this.router.navigate([], {queryParams: {search: term}});
  ```
- When the query-string changes, the search mechanism should take the search-term from the query-string:

  ```
  this.heroes$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
        // take the search term from the query string
        map(query=>query.search),
        ...
  ```
- When the page reloads, take the search term to the model:

  ```
  this.term = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.search;
  ```

  To achieve this use Two-Way Binding:

  ```
  <input #searchBox [(ngModel)]="term" id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  ```

So it's should be something like this:

```
  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  // change the query string when the user type
  search(term: string): void {
    this.router.navigate([], {queryParams: {search: term}});
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // take the current search term
    this.term = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.search;

    this.heroes$ = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      // take the search term from the query string
      map(query=>query.search),

      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
    );
  }
```

See a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2reft-nrus96)

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular's [two-way binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding-) functionality.

Then instead of having only one-way binding like this:

```
<input #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />
```

You can two-way-bind the `ngModel`-property of the `input` element to an attribute inside your component:

```
<input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchQuery)" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" />
```

The `(keyup)`-event gets called every time the user enters a new character (and let's go off a keypress).